# When trying to flash DD-WRT on my Linksys 1900AC, it keeps reverting back to OEM software

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I've tried flashing DD-WRT using the `factory-to-ddwrt.bin` file I downloaded using the GUI.

However, when I go to the default gateway, it stays with the OEM Linksys firmware.

Did some research, and I discovered this router has dual partitions. To switch to the second partition, I tried power cycling 3-4 times like indicated, but it still didn't work. Couldn't find any other alternative.

Did I forget something here?

Comment: Did you get the firmware from the router database page? And not from https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/ ???

Comment: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firmware_FAQ#Where_do_I_download_firmware.3F

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I got it from here https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=WRT1900AC_v1

Comment: Use the first link. Read the warning in the second. Using firmware from the router database can permeantly brick a device. Yours has two physical flash chips, so it's alot harder to brick them.

Comment: Did that work out for you?